# How is the order of callbacks scheduled?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I'd like to kick off an HttpRequest and then poll for its completion. This feels like a fairly common pattern.

```
void main() {
  _tick(0);
  _tickB(0);
  build();
  print("End of main");
}

void build() {
  var path = '../layout.txt';
  html.HttpRequest.getString(path).then((String layout) {
    print("layout received");
  });
}

void _tick(int i) {
  print("A $i");

  if (i < 10) incr(i).then(_tick);
}

void _tickB(int i) {
  print("B $i");

  if (i < 10) incr(i).then(_tickB);
}

Future<int> incr(int i) async {
  i++;
  return i;
}
```

Output:

```
A1
B1
End of main
A2
B2
A3
B3
A4
B4
A5
B5
layout received
```

I would expect to see "layout received" appear interleaved with the other callbacks when the HttpRequest completes but its not. Its always (no matter the value of `i`, 5 is just a demo number) at the end of the interleaved callbacks.

Why is this?
How can I schedule the `build` callback in such a way that it completes during the other callback chains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `incr` function doesn't actually do any asynchronous work.  `incr` will be executed to completion immediately.  Since the returned `Future` is already complete, its `Future.then` callbacks then will be scheduled in the *microtask* queue.  Only after the microtask queue is empty will the separate *event* queue be processed.  Your `_tick`/`_tickB` functions therefore create a (temporary) live-lock situation by repeatedly adding events to the microtask queue and preventing your `HttpRequest` `Future` from completing.

You can get the behavior you expect by making `incr` do some asynchronous work:

```dart
Future<int> incr(int i) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  i++;
  return i;
}
```

and then your output will be:

```
A 0
B 0
End of main
A 1
B 1
layout received
A 2
B 2
A 3
B 3
...
```

Further reading: [The Event Loop and Dart](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop)

Comment: I think the content of "The Event Loop and Dart" has been more or less moved to: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency

Comment: This definitely appears to be the issue. I am curious if there's more modern docs on event vs microtask queue though. The "alternative" article above literally does not mention the microtask queue once.

Comment: @julemand101 Seems like "less" since that doesn't mention microtasks at all. =( I'm not aware of more recent documentation; the direct replacement for the "Event Loop and Dart" article is https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a, but that doesn't discuss microtasks either (and directs people to the old archive.org copy for those details).