# Execution order of Future and Stream

Tags: dart

If stream and future are mixed, I don't know in what order they will be added to the event queue.
I ran the following code and got unexpected results.

```
void main() async {
  stream().listen(print);
  await (() async => print('3'))();
  await (() async => print('4'))();
  await (() async => print('5'))();
}

Stream<int> stream() async* {
  print('1');
  yield 2;
}
```

I expected the following result.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

but actual result is

```
3
1
4
2
5
```

From this result, it seems that the processing of stream is added to the event queue with a slight delay.
If I add a little delay before Future, expected result is got.
Why does it have this kind of result?

Comment: When you execute an asynchronous function, as much of that function as possible is executed synchronously.  That is, it will immediately execute everything in that function until the function reaches an `await` or returns a `Future`.  Therefore, `await (() async => print('3'))();` executes the `print` call immediately.  Since the `Future` is already complete, its completion callback (which will proceed to the `print('4')` step) will be scheduled in the microtask queue, which is processed before the event queue.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72695745/

Answer (score 2):

You should not, ever, assume anything about the interleaving of independent asynchronous operations.

What you see is an accident of implementation. It could easily have been different.

Currently, the beginning of `async*` functions are delayed (scheduled for a later microtask when you listen to the stream). That's [not actually the desired behavior](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1759), it's just hard to change. That's why `1` isn't printed immediately when you call `listen` on the stream.

The `yield` may or may not introduce a further delay. Again, nothing is promised. It may be possible to [deliver the event immediately after the `yield`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48695). The current implementation doesn't.

What you can assume is that the stream events do happen in order, and the awaited futures happen one after another (because of the `await`s).
The interleaving is entirely incidental.

*Most likely* delayed operations are delayed by using a scheduled microtask, putting it at the end of the current microtask queue. There is no promise that that's always going to be the case.

*Do not* rely on specific interleavings of independent asynchronous events. If you do, it makes it much harder to make the `dart:async` libraries more efficient in the future, if they have to preserve the specific interleaving that your code has chosen to depend on.
We all want more efficient libraries, right?

Now, if you actually *wanted* the stream to complete before continuing, you could change `stream().listen(print);` into `await stream().forEach(print);`, or maybe even `await for (var value in stream) { print(value); }`.